# mvc routing issue when launching another controller from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view with a HTML.action link that launches a controller/action. The action that launched the view and the action inside the view have the same controller.
I get an error: 
**"The controller for path '/DB/carDB' was not found or does not implement IController."**

**The controller:**

```
public class DBController : Controller
{        
    // GET: /DB/        
    cartableContext cdc = new cartableContext();//connect to the sql express database.

//This action creates a view that will launch the action below
    public ActionResult carDB()
     {   
         List<Cardata> cd = cdc.cardata.ToList();            
         return View(cd);
     }


//This action will be in a HTML.action link
    public ActionResult cardetails(string id)
    {
        Cardata details = cdc.cardata.Single(det => det.model == id);
        return View(details);
    }    
{
```

**The view** (This is the line that crashes):

```
model: <%Html.Action(cardata.model, "~/cardetails");%>
```

I tried

model: Html.Action(cardata.model, "cardetails");

model: Html.Action(cardata.model, "/DB/cardetails");

I also tried creating another route.maprout in global.asax but no luck so I returned the file to it's default

How can I get the view's action to start at /DB/ not /DB/carDB?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting Html.Action or Html.ActionLink? (and you have your parameters mixed up)

Comment: Yes I needed action link: =Html.ActionLink(cardata.model, "cardetails", new { id = cardata.model }) . Now the second parameter is being treated like a view rather than an action

Comment: Then use `Html.ActionLink("cardetails", new { id = "SomeValue" })`

Comment: Being a noob, I misinterpreted an error. My cardetails view was missing. Adding the view solved the last problem. Thanks